# Why can template<T> but not template<> be defined outside of a namespace block?

Tags: c++, templates

Here is some code which does not compile.

```
namespace ns
{
    class foo
    {
        template <typename T> int bar (T *);
    };
}

template <typename T>
int ns :: foo :: bar (T*) // this is OK
{
    return 0;
}

template <>
int ns :: foo :: bar <int> (int *) // this is an error
{
    return 1;
}
```

The error is: "specialisation of ‘template int ns::foo::bar(T*)’ in different namespace [-fpermissive] from definition of ‘template int ns::foo::bar(T*)"

Here is a version which does compile:

```
namespace ns
{
    class foo
    {
        template <typename T> int bar (T *);
    };
}

template <typename T>
int ns :: foo :: bar (T*)
{
    return 0;
}

namespace ns
{
    template <>
    int foo :: bar <int> (int *)
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Why does the second definition have to be in a `namespace ns {}` block when the first one is quite happily defined with a qualified name? Is it just an oversight in the language design or is there a reason for this?

Comment: Now that I look at it, C++11 § 14.7.3/2 is for the decl, not the def.  But I think 14.7.3/8 still applies. The wording at the end of 14.7.3/7  is *awesome*: "When writing a specialization, be careful about its location; or to make it compile will be such a trial as to kindle its self-immolation."

Comment: [possible duplicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052579/explicit-specialization-in-non-namespace-scope)

Comment: Heh. according to Georg it *is* in fact 14.7.3/2. Teach *me* to second guess myself.

Comment: another similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072248/why-arent-template-specializations-allowed-to-be-in-different-namespaces

Comment: That relates to which namespace a function lives in, but this question is about why the namespace must be expressed in a particular (equivalent) way.

Comment: @spraff: The problem is not where the element is *defined*, but rather where it is *declared*. You can *define* it as you want, but you need to provide a declaration in the appropriate namespace.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem here is not the *definition*, but the *declaration*. You cannot inject a declaration in a namespace from a different namespace, so the specialization *must* be declared in the appropriate namespace before it can be *defined* in any enclosing namespace.

The definition of the base template can be done in the outer namespace because it has already been *declared*, so the code in the outer namespace provides a definition but does not inject any declaration into the namespace.

Try:

```
namespace ns {
    class foo
    {
        template <typename T> int bar (T *);
    };
    template <>
    int foo::bar<int>(int*); // declaration
}
template <typename T>
int ns :: foo :: bar (T*) {
    return 0;
}
template <>
int ns :: foo :: bar <int> (int *) {
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: +1 This makes *perfect* sense. I think this was the fundamental behind 14.7.3/2. Thanks for the clarity, David.

Comment: Thanks, but can you please clarify: how is line 5 in my original code `template <typename T> int bar (T *);` *not* a declaration?

Comment: @spraff: It *is* a declaration, but not a declaration than a specialization exist.

Comment: Perhaps this is a silly question, but why must a declaration that a specialization exist exist?

Comment: @spraff: A definition is a declaration, 8.3/1 requires that a declaration in which the *declarator-id* is qualified (as is your case) the it must refer to a previously declared member of the class or namespace to which the qualifier refers. (Informally I usually say that a *definition* outside the namespaace is not a *declaration*, but that is really not the case, it is just that it requires of a previous declaration within the namespace)