# Boost.Test Custom Type using decorator boost::unit_test::tolerance

Tags: c++, boost-test

I'm using Boost.Test to test for numerical values quite a lot. Often I have to compare the values of mathematical objects. Below is a toy example showing how I have to test quite a lot.

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE VektorTest
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
#include <boost/test/floating_point_comparison.hpp> 

struct Vector {
    Vector(double x, double y, double z) : x(x), y(y), z(z) {}
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
};

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(Rotations, * boost::unit_test::tolerance(1.0e-2)) {
    Vector vector1(1.5,3.,7.4);
    Vector vector2(1.51, 3.01, 7.41);

    // The following can get really annoying and is error prone.
    BOOST_TEST(vector1.x==vector2.x);
    BOOST_TEST(vector1.y==vector2.y);
    BOOST_TEST(vector1.z==vector2.z);

    // This should be the expected usage, but only if the tolerance is considered.
    // BOOST_TEST(vector1==vector2); // Will not compile!
}
```

Can I teach Boost.Test to recognize custom types that consider the `boost::unit_test::tolerance` decorator?

A mere one-to-one comparison of the contents `x,y,z` of the `Vector` object will be no workable solution.

#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE VektorTest
 #include 
 #include

struct Vector {
    Vector(double x, double y, double z) : x(x), y(y), z(z) {}

```
double x;
double y;
double z;
```

};

**Edit**

After I studied the documentation of Boost.Test more closely I found the interesting function `per_element()`, that allowed the comparison of values being contained in sequences. This function is already a great benefit, as it considers the `tolerance` decorator, as exemplified below. An `std::vector<T>` satisfies the sequence interface and can be nicely used within this framework.

The Boost.Test documentation says, that a sequence should implement the `size()` and `begin()` functions, as well as the fields `const_iterator` and `value_type`. As for me that is not a workable solution, as I'm not able to change the interface of the mathematical classes. Even more I was not able to extend the below toy example to satisfy this interface.

```
 #define BOOST_TEST_MODULE VektorTest
 #include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
 #include <boost/test/floating_point_comparison.hpp> 

 struct Vector {
    Vector(double x, double y, double z) : x(x), y(y), z(z) {}

    double x;
    double y;
    double z;

 };

 BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(VectorTest, * boost::unit_test::tolerance(1.0e-4)) {
     {
         std::vector<double> vector1;
         vector1.push_back(1.5);
         vector1.push_back(3.);
         vector1.push_back(7.4);

         std::vector<double> vector2;
         vector2.push_back(1.51);
         vector2.push_back(3.01);
         vector2.push_back(7.41);
         BOOST_TEST(vector1==vector2, boost::test_tools::per_element());
     }

     {
         Vector vector1(1.5,3.,7.4);
         Vector vector2(1.51, 3.01, 7.41);

         //BOOST_TEST(vector1==vector2, boost::test_tools::per_element()); // Will not compile!!!
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure to understand fully your question, but maybe `BOOST_TEST_SPECIALIZED_COLLECTION_COMPARE` (see [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/testing_tools/extended_comparison/collections.html)) is the answer to your question.

## Edit: the virtuous and complicated way

If you want to consider your `Vektor` as a type on which tolerance based comparison should be performed, then you may look [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/testing_tools/extended_comparison/floating_point/customizing_for_tolerance.html) in the documentation

What you need is:

- make your class compatible with the tolerance based comparison (needs `EqualityComparable`, `LessThanComparable`). All comparison (see [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/testing_tools/extended_comparison/floating_point/floating_points_comparison_impl.html) and [there](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/testing_tools/extended_comparison/floating_point/floating_points_comparison_theory.html)) operations involve a difference between two values to be computed, so you need your class to implement `LessThanComparable`, negation - for absolute value - and construction from a single value - needed for the origin -. `boost.operators` might be of a good help here.
- notify boost.test that your class is compatible with tolerance based operations by declaring a specialization of `tolerance_based` for your class

In your case, the tolerance region that you want to achieve is within 3D cube around a specific location. Given a tolerance \epsilon,

- vectors that fall inside this cube are "close enough" wrt. \epsilon
- vectors falling outside the cube are considered as "far enough"

All those operations are performed by [close_at_tolerance](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost/math/fpc/close_at_tolerance.html).

Since you want to performs the tolerance per axis, you may implement

- `operator-` as the diff per axis
- `operator-` (unary negation) as the negation per axis
- `operator<` as a comparison per axis
- `operator/` as a division per axis

etc. `operator<` and `operator-` (unary) are used for computing the absolute value.

However, this will not work as expected as `std::max` and `std::min` should also be implemented (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3072399/1617295)). In your case, they should provide the `max` and `min` per axis. Currently

- the easiest would be to implement your specialization of `close_at_tolerance` (see [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/boost/test/tools/floating_point_comparison.hpp)).
- or implement `std::min` and `std::max` and specialize `boost::math::fpc::fpc_detail::fpt_abs` (private API) for computing the absolute value.

At the end of the day, it is just a matter of comparisons wrt. tolerances, differences and absolute value computation.

If you take

```
|v1 - v2| = (|a1-a2|, |b1-b2|, |c1-c2|)
|v1 - v2|/|v1| = (|a1-a2|/|a1|, |b1-b2|/|b1|, |c1-c2|/|c1|) // same for v2
max(|v1 - v2|/|v1|, |v1 - v2|/|v2|) = (max(|a1-a2|/|a1|, |a1-a2|/|a2|),
                                       max(|b1-b2|/|b1|, |b1-b2|/|b2|),                              
                                       ... )
```

What is needed for performing a test is:

```
|v1 - v2|/|v1| < eps. && |v1 - v2|/|v2| < eps.
=>   max(|v1 - v2|/|v1|, |v1 - v2|/|v2|) < eps.
=>   max(|v1 - v2|/|v1|, |v1 - v2|/|v2|) < vektor(eps., eps., eps.)
=>     max(|a1-a2|/|a1|, |a1-a2|/|a2|) < eps. 
       && max(|b1-b2|/|b1|, |b1-b2|/|b2|) < eps. ...
```

and it becomes consistent with max, division and comparison per axis.

Comment: Thanks for your link. I made some progress in answering my question, but still I was not able to grasp it to the full extent. I just extended my question.