# Creating an "instance" of a static template class inside an another namespace

Tags: c++, templates, static, namespaces, template-specialization

There is a "static template" class which is used for an enum to string  conversion.

The code below generates an unreadable set of template related errors in **enum.cpp**:

```cpp
//helpers.hpp
namespace helpers {
template<typename T>
class Convert {
public:    
    static std::string toStr(T) { return m_convert.at(T); }

private:
    static std::map<T, std::string> m_convert;
};
}
...

//enum.hpp
namespace A::B::C::D {
enum class ImportantEnum {
    item1,
    item2,
};
}
...

//enum.cpp
#include "helpers.hpp"
#include "enum.hpp"

namespace A::B::C::D {
template<>
std::map<ImportantEnum, std::string> helpers::Convert<ImportantEnum>::m_convert = {
    {ImportantEnum::item1, "item1"},
    {ImportantEnum::item2, "item2"},
}
}
...

//enum_lover.cpp
#include "helpers.hpp"
#include "enum.hpp"

namespace A::B::C::D {
void do() {
    std::string s = helpers::Convert<ImportantEnum>::toStr(ImportantEnum::item1);
}
}
```

All works good if I use the code below in **enum.cpp**:

```cpp
//enum.cpp
#include "helpers.hpp"
#include "enum.hpp"

namespace A::B::C::D {
template<>
std::map<A::B::C::D::ImportantEnum, std::string>
helpers::Convert<A::B::C::D::ImportantEnum>::m_convert = {
    {A::B::C::D::ImportantEnum::item1, "item1"},
    {A::B::C::D::ImportantEnum::item2, "item2"},
}
}
```

Is it possible to implement this kind of helper in a more convenient way from namespaces point of view?

**Why the trick** with long "A::B::C::D::ImportantEnum" declaration is required in enum.cpp? It is already inside the A::B::C::D namespase...

### Updated:

Here is the similar discussion:
[Why aren't template specializations allowed to be in different namespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072248/why-arent-template-specializations-allowed-to-be-in-different-namespaces)

Comment: please show a [mre] and the error messages

Comment: "static template class" isnt a thing. Its a class template with only static members. As it has no non static members, its of no use to create an instance of it. I have to read more, perhaps its just the wording that is off and you want to instantiate the class template? To get a class? Not to get an instance of that class?

Comment: "Static template" here the template that has static methods and static members only. All work doing without instantiation

Comment: there is no `helpers::m_convert`. THere is `helpers::Convert<T>::m_convert` though. Looks like important parts were removed from the code

Comment: please post a [mcve] and include the compiler error in the quesiton. The error is indeed unreadable, because you did not include it in the post

Comment: 463035818_is_not_an_ai, fixed, my bad sorry

Comment: `do` is a keyword. `return m_convert[T];` makes no sense. `...do conversion...` triggers a syntax error, there are missing `;`, missing includes, and there is so much more that triggers compiler errors in this code that it is totally unclear what error this question is about. Please provide a [mcve] and the compiler error message

Comment: if you want to convert `enum` to string then just search for it in SO. It's an old problem, with lots of partial and suboptimal solutions. **Never try to reinvent the wheel**.

Comment: I want to understand how wheels work. My sandbox is a good way for that...

Answer (score 0):

Since I posted my original answer, you have edited the code in your original question. This answer is in reply to [Revision 33](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77266830/revisions).

One change you made is to add scoping to the enumeration constants. With a *scoped enumeration*, the constants must always be preceded by the enum class name.

Your file names are a bit confusing. The file you named `enum.cpp` would be named `helpers.cpp` by many programmers. That way, the declaration for class template `Convert` would go in `helpers.hpp`, while the definitions for its members would go in `helpers.cpp`. In this case, however, using `enum.cpp` will not prevent the code from compiling, so I left the file name unchanged. Note, however, that with the addition of `AnotherEnum`, it is awkward to have `Convert<AnotherEnum>::m_convert` defined in file `enum.cpp`.

The question you linked, [Why aren't template specializations allowed to be in different namespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3072399/22193627), discusses specializations of the templates in the Standard Library, and the fact that they should be placed in namespace `std`. It does not really apply to what you are trying to do.

Here are some of the other things I noticed. Many of the compiler errors you are getting are related to these issues. These notes are sequenced in the same order as the corresponding files are in your OP.

**helpers.hpp**

- Needs include-guard, e.g., `#ifndef HELPERS_HPP`, and so on.
- Uses `std::map`, but fails to include header `<map>`
- Uses `std::string`, but fails to include header `<string>`
- Definition of function `toStr` does not supply a parameter name. I added `e`, and used it as the argument in the call of function `at`.

**enum.hpp**

- Needs include-guard, e.g., `#ifndef ENUM_HPP`, and so on.

**enum.cpp (first version and second version have same issues)**

- Uses `std::map`, but fails to include header `<map>`
- Uses `std::string`, but fails to include header `<string>`
- Somewhat oddly, it places the definition of `m_convert` in namespace `A::B::C::D`, instead of in namespace `helpers`, where it is declared.
- Missing semi-colon (;), after the closing brace of the initializer for `m_convert`.

**enum_lover.cpp**

- Uses `std::string`, but fails to include header `<string>`
- Uses keyword `do` as a function name. I changed it to `do_it`.

You ask:

> Is it possible to implement this kind of helper in a more convenient way from namespaces point of view?

One way is to strategically place *using declarations* in your source code. That is what I have done in the program below. In file `helpers.hpp`, right before the declaration of function template `Convert`, I added using declarations for the two `enum`s I used by the program.

```cpp
namespace helpers {
    using A::B::C::D::ImportantEnum;
    using A::AnotherEnum;
    template<typename T>
    class Convert { ... };
}
```

###### A solution using class template specializations

Here is a running program based on the code in the OP. In order to make things a bit more interesting, I added a second enumeration, and placed it in a different namespace.

```cpp
// enum.hpp
#ifndef ENUM_HPP
#define ENUM_HPP
namespace A::B::C::D {
    enum class ImportantEnum {
        item1,
        item2,
    };
}
#endif
// end file: enum.hpp
```

```cpp
// AnotherEnum.hpp
#ifndef ANOTHER_ENUM_HPP
#define ANOTHER_ENUM_HPP
namespace A {
    // Note that this enum is not in the same namespace 
    // as ImportantEnum. That should make things more interesting.
    enum class AnotherEnum {
        another_item1,
        another_item2,
    };
}
#endif
// end file: AnotherEnum.hpp
```

The only modifications to header `helpers.hpp` (besides the fixes described above) was to include the header `AnotherEnum.hpp`, and add using declarations for `ImportantEnum` and `AnotherEnum`.

```cpp
// helpers.hpp
#ifndef HELPERS_HPP
#define HELPERS_HPP
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include "enum.hpp"
#include "AnotherEnum.hpp"

namespace helpers {
    // Add using declarations for the enumerations you need 
    // to convert into strings. This simplifies the definitions 
    // of `m_convert` given in file `enum.cpp`, and may help 
    // with certain ADL operations as well (see `enum_lover.cpp`).
    using A::B::C::D::ImportantEnum;
    using A::AnotherEnum;

    template<typename T>
    class Convert {
    public:
        static std::string toStr(T e) { return m_convert.at(e); }

    private:
        static std::map<T, std::string> m_convert;
    };
}
#endif
// end file: helpers.hpp
```

In file `enum.cpp`, I moved the definitions for `m_convert` into namespace `helpers`. Now, there are no scoping operations in file `enum.cpp`.

```cpp
// enum.cpp
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include "helpers.hpp"
#include "enum.hpp"
#include "AnotherEnum.hpp"
namespace helpers {
    template<>
    std::map<ImportantEnum, std::string> Convert<ImportantEnum>::m_convert = {
        { ImportantEnum::item1, "item1" },
        { ImportantEnum::item2, "item2" },
    };
    template<>
    std::map<AnotherEnum, std::string> Convert<AnotherEnum>::m_convert = {
        { AnotherEnum::another_item1, "another_item1" },
        { AnotherEnum::another_item2, "another_item2" },
    };
}
// end file: enum.cpp
```

I created the following header for file `enum_lover.cpp`. Interestingly, I did not include it there. It is included in `main.cpp`.

```cpp
// enum_lover.hpp
#ifndef ENUM_LOVER_HPP
#define ENUM_LOVER_HPP
namespace A::B::C::D {
    void do_it();
}
#endif
// end file: enum_lover.hpp
```

In file `enum_lover.cpp`, I added an output statement, so that we can see the results of function `toStr`. I think we are getting some help from ADL (argument dependent lookup), because otherwise, `A::AnotherEnum` should require scoping.

```cpp
// enum_lover.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "enum.hpp"
#include "AnotherEnum.hpp"
#include "helpers.hpp"
namespace A::B::C::D {
    void do_it() {
        std::string s = helpers::Convert<ImportantEnum>::toStr(ImportantEnum::item1);
        std::cout
            << helpers::Convert<ImportantEnum>::toStr(ImportantEnum::item1) << '\n'
            << helpers::Convert<ImportantEnum>::toStr(ImportantEnum::item2) << '\n'
            << helpers::Convert<AnotherEnum>::toStr(AnotherEnum::another_item1) << '\n'
            << helpers::Convert<AnotherEnum>::toStr(AnotherEnum::another_item2) << '\n';
    }
}
// end file: enum_lover.cpp
```

Finally, we have function `main`, which calls function `do_it` to run the tests.

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include "enum_lover.hpp"
int main()
{
    A::B::C::D::do_it();
    return 0;
}
// end file: main.cpp
```

Here is the output:

```
item1
item2
another_item1
another_item2
```

###### Just give me the syntantic sugar!

A much shorter and friendlier way to do this is to get rid of the class template entirely. Just go with function overloads. You can define them at the point of definition for each of the enums (easy), or collect them all in a separate file (more cumbersome).

If you leave each function definition in the same namespace as the enum that it uses, you will minimize namespace scoping. At worst, you will have to scope either the function name or its argument, but not both.

The functions are all declared inline, so that they can be defined in a header without generating duplicate definition errors.

```cpp
// enum.hpp
#ifndef ENUM_HPP
#define ENUM_HPP
#include <map>
#include <string>
namespace A::B::C::D {
    enum class ImportantEnum {
        item1 = 42,
        item2,
    };
    inline std::string toStr(ImportantEnum const e) {
        static std::map<ImportantEnum, std::string> lookup{
            { ImportantEnum::item1, "item1" },
            { ImportantEnum::item2, "item2" },
        };
        return lookup.at(e);
    }
}
#endif
// end file: enum.hpp
```

```cpp
// AnotherEnum.hpp
#ifndef ANOTHER_ENUM_HPP
#define ANOTHER_ENUM_HPP
#include <map>
#include <string>
namespace A {
    enum class AnotherEnum {
        another_item1,
        another_item2,
    };
    inline std::string toStr(AnotherEnum const e) {
        static std::map<AnotherEnum, std::string> lookup{
            { AnotherEnum::another_item1, "another_item1" },
            { AnotherEnum::another_item2, "another_item2" },
        };
        return lookup.at(e);
    }
}
#endif
// end file: AnotherEnum.hpp
```

Given the small number of enumeration constants, a simple `switch` statement may be more efficient that using `std::map`. I guess you would have to test, however, to be sure.

Comment: I have dozens enums distributed other the code. Idea was - to create a template, and do the map redefinition in place... The question why I need to do the A::B::C::D:: definitions if I already in that namespace. Why the code listed in first example is not correct...

Comment: @Anders Brodin: I updated my answer, so that it conforms to the latest edits of your question. Hope this helps.